# My crystal cannot populate anything from two tables

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

function to display day to day report for unpaid invoices

```
Public Sub DayToDayUnpaidInvoice()
    Try
        connection.Open()
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT tblclientinfo.Client_ID, tblclientinfo.C_name, tblclientinfo.C_surname, tblinv_info.inv_Num , tblinv_info.Inv_date  
                            FROM tblclientinfo,tblinv_info 
                            WHERE tblclientinfo.Client_ID = tblinv_info.Client_ID AND inv_paid = 'N' OR inv_paid = '' 
                            ORDER BY inv_date ASC;"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, connection)
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter()
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "tblclientinfo")
        Dim report As New DayToDayUnpaid
        report.SetDataSource(ds)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
        cmd.Dispose()
        da.Dispose()
        ds.Dispose()
        connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        connection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: So what is the problem?  Error?  or just no data?  Does the query return the expected data if you query the DB directly via query tools?

Comment: No data, only the headings, I have used the same code to query some information from one table and fortunately it works fine, but I'm struggling when there are two tables, thanks.

Comment: When I use other tools, the query gives me expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
report.SetDataSource(ds)
```

to this

```
report.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
```

Comment: Thanks I will do so, furthermore if I can ask since I'm querying from two tables this line of code here is ok like this :da.Fill(ds, "tblclientinfo") or must I include two table names

Comment: that's fine. your query will only return one table

Comment: I understand, but my query is requesting data from two table hence I was concerned about this da. Fill function, kindly advise.

Comment: You can see how many tables your query returns by Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables.Count)

Comment: Can I rephrase my question, how can I use the provided code to retrieve information from two tables, or rather where em I missing it?

Comment: @Ximba_J Should be a new question but anyway. I've only ever done this in MSSQL, might be a bit different in MySql. You can do multiple queries in your command seperated by a semi colon.  eg "Select * from tblclientinfo;Select * from tblinv_info"

Comment: what @hursey said.